# Swift - Cant change color of toolbar

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the color of my toolbar like so:

```
self.navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

When I print my `self.navigationController?.toolbar`, it returns the following.

```
Optional(<UIToolbar: 0x100c7b5b0; frame = (0 623; 375 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x100c7b9c0>>)
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try barTintColor instead :

```
 self.navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change the bar color of `navigation`, if yes then use `navigationBar` property of `navigationController` set the `barTintColor` like this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```